# PyCharm не видит методы OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

PyCharm ругается при обращении к методам модуля cv2:
[image: Cannot find reference]

Также не работает автокомплит в редакторе кода, но в консоле все работает нормально:
[image: Python console]

При этом всем код запускается и работает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у Вас в проекте есть файл `cv2.py`. Переименуйте его и всё заработает. Консоль о нём не знает из-за того, что он не в корне

Comment: Нет, проект состоит всего из одного файла first.py, так что переименовывать просто нечего

Comment: Тогда попробуйте навести курсор на название метода и сделать Ctrl+Click. И посмотрите какой файл откроется в редакторе

Comment: По нажатию на метод пишет Cannot find declaration to go to, но если нажать на имя модуля, то открывает файл Python36\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py

Comment: Теперь нужно посмотреть, какие методы есть в этом файле. И у opencv и у его питоновской обёртки есть по две актуальные версии - вторая и третья. С разными API

Comment: Вот весь код из файала: https://pastebin.com/zkZXYppX

Comment: посмотрите ответы из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm